# Porquê a model retorna nula depois de usar o AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, console-application

A `model Endereco` retorna nula após o mapeamento ([AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)), porquê ?

Exemplo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AutoMapperDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeAutomapper();

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente()
            {
                ClienteID = 1,
                Nome = "João da Silva",
                CPF = "111.888.999-99"
            };

            Endereco end1 = new Endereco();
            end1.EnderecoID = 1;
            end1.ClienteID = 1;
            end1.Logradouro = "Rua XV de Novembro, 151";
            end1.CEP = "01000-000";
            cliente.Endereco.Add(end1);

            Endereco end2 = new Endereco();
            end2.EnderecoID = 2;
            end2.ClienteID = 1;
            end2.Logradouro = "Av. Interlagos, 1200";
            end2.CEP = "03450-000";
            cliente.Endereco.Add(end2);

            var clienteDTO = Mapper.Map<Cliente, ClienteDTO>(cliente);

            Console.WriteLine("Cliente ID::" + clienteDTO.ClienteID + ", Nome: " + clienteDTO.Nome + ", CPF: " + clienteDTO.CPF);
            Console.WriteLine("Endereço Cliente 1 ID:" + clienteDTO.EnderecoDTO[0].EnderecoID + ", Logradouro: " + clienteDTO.EnderecoDTO[0].Logradouro + ", CEP: " + clienteDTO.EnderecoDTO[0].CEP);
            Console.WriteLine("Endereço Cliente 2 ID:" + clienteDTO.EnderecoDTO[1].EnderecoID + ", Logradouro: " + clienteDTO.EnderecoDTO[1].Logradouro + ", CEP: " + clienteDTO.EnderecoDTO[1].CEP);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void InitializeAutomapper()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoDTO>();
            });
        }
    }

    public class Cliente
    {
        public Cliente()
        {
            Endereco = new List<Endereco>();
        }
        public int ClienteID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public List<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
    }
    public class Endereco
    {
        public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
        public int ClienteID { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string   CEP { get; set; }
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClienteDTO
    {
        public int ClienteID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public List<EnderecoDTO> EnderecoDTO { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnderecoDTO
    {
        public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
        public int ClienteID { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string CEP { get; set; }
        public ClienteDTO ClienteDTO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: não mapeou nada, inclusive o ClienteID?

Comment: Olá @Ricardo Pontual exatamente ! Não mapeou nada ! Inclusive editei o post e acrescentei um print do código em execução.

Comment: pelo seu print não mapeou só a lista de endereços certo? tente configurar o mapper assim: `cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteDTO>().ForMember(s => s.EnderecoDTO, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.Endereco));`  veja se mapeia corretamente e posso colocar a sintaxe explicando numa resposta

Comment: Obrigado @Ricardo Pontual implementei sua sugestão porém ocorre essa exceção: `Error mapping types. Mapping types: Cliente -> ClienteDTO AutoMapperDemo.Cliente -> AutoMapperDemo.ClienteDTO 
Type Map configuration: Cliente -> ClienteDTO AutoMapperDemo.Cliente ->  AutoMapperDemo.ClienteDTO Destination Member: EnderecoDTO` .

Comment: mas depois daquela linha vc manteve o mapper do endereço né? `cfg.CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoDTO>();`

Comment: Eu havia retirado por isso que não funcionou, daí então adicionei e funcionou perfeitamente ! Obrigado ! Você pode responder separado a solução para eu finalizar o post e marcar como certo ?

Comment: pronto, respondida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não estava mapeando corretamento porque, embora tivesse sido definido o mapper para os tipos de endereço (`cfg.CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoDTO>();`), na classe `Cliente`, a propriedade é um `List<Endereco>`.

Por isso é importante informar ao `Automapper` como mapear corretamente a propriedade `Endereco`, ficando assim:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteDTO>()
                   .ForMember(s => s.EnderecoDTO, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.Endereco));
                cfg.CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoDTO>();
            });
```

Desta forma o `Automapper` sabe como mapear do tipo `Endereco` para `EnderecoDTO` e também sabe que o membro `EnderecoDTO` da classe `ClienteDTO` será mapeado a partir do membro `Endereco` da classe `Cliente`.

Apenas um comentário: como são listas, sugiro usar o nome da propriedade no plural, o que ajuda também a distinguir do nome da classe:

```
public List<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
```

e

```
public List<EnderecoDTO> EnderecosDTO { get; set; }
```